# What is the meaning of this expression ? 腕に + an Object + 押しくら饅頭 (pushing something towards someone ??)

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

Hope someone can help me understand correctly this action/ expression.

MC come to watch his senpai practicing beach volley ball, then MC describes his senpai's action :"**ムニュっと腕に豊満すぎるY先輩のおっぱいが押しくら饅頭**"

I can only guess its meaning: (please correct me if I was wrong)

1/ His senpai using her arms to push her cleavage together

2/His senpai push her boobs toward MC's arm

Answer (score 1):

The 押しくら饅頭 is just a pun and does not particularly mean more than 押す/押し付け（られている）.

As for your understanding, it is more just 2 and there is no implication (from that sentence alone) about cleavage.

- ムニュっと : onomatopoeia describing something soft (in this case, breast) pushing against something
- 腕に : to the arm (this should refer to MC's arms)
- 豊満すぎる : too voluptuous
- Y先輩のおっぱいが : Y senpai's breast
- 押しくら饅頭 : pushing

---

But generally, this kind of pun is literally meaningless. I think the pun in question is made in the same way as [what is listed in 掛詞 here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9C%B0%E5%8F%A3).

Picking a few (famous ones)

- あたり前田のクラッカー - 「当たり**前{まえ}だ**」と「**前田{まえだ}**のクラッカー」
- 恐れ入谷の鬼子母神 - 「恐れ**入{い}り**ました」と「**[入]{いり}**谷{や}の鬼子母神」

The first phrases are made simply by joining the bold parts - again simply because they share the same sound. For the one in question, similarly **押し**付けられている and **押し**くら饅頭 are joined.

Another thing is that probably 饅頭 refers to breast.

Comment: yeah this is really hard for my JP level to understand kanji wordplay. Can you please explain the word play here ?

Comment: @casualreader I added in the answer - but I'm not sure it makes much sense to you.