# Is the grammar of いただき in continuative form [連用形] or in dialectical imperative form

Tags: grammar, dialects, imperatives, form

I am having trouble deciphering the meaning of this lyric:

> 指切りげんまん ホラでも吹いたら
>
> **針でもなんでも 飲ませていただき Monday**

Is the word **飲ませていただき** in the imperative form as [in Kansai [書き -write it]](http://www.kansaiben.com/4.FunctionalGrammar/3.Imperatives/2.Grammar/1G.html)  or is this in standard continuative form

My translation:

連用形 form: Monday on which you let me be swallowing needles or whatever

Imperative form: Let swallow needles or whatever, [on] monday

From the idiomatic expression:

> 指切拳万、嘘ついたら針千本呑ます

Comment: It is  the same type of pun mentioned in https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/97569/45489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that song, but I think it is a pun. In kansai, people uses ”～しまんで！” instead of ”～しますよ”. So it is a pun on the words ”飲ませていただきまんで！” and ”飲ませていただきマンデー(Monday)”.

Therefore, the meaning is ”If I should tell a lie, I could swalloWednesday the needles!”
(When I try to make such a pun in English, I had to use Wednesday.)

By the way, merely ”飲ませていただき！” is not used even kansai.

Comment: 関西の終助詞の「で」って、「ね」じゃなく「よ」のほうに近いんじゃないでしょうか？

Comment: 調べてみたらそんな気がしますね！兵庫に住んでるので、(大阪の南の方の)強い関西弁はあまり得意じゃないんです…